# How can I remove a number if it exists in the vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Take this code:

```
using ColumnIndexVector = std::vector<int>;
ColumnIndexVector m_vColumnIndexesToExclude;

bool bModified = false;

for (int iColumn = 1; iColumn < m_Grid.GetColumnCount(); iColumn++)
{
    if (m_bNotUsed) // Not used
    {
        if (m_vColumnIndexesToExclude.erase(iColumn) > 0)
        {
            bModified = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The line `if (m_vColumnIndexesToExclude.erase(iColumn) > 0)` will not compile. I complains that `iColumn` is not a `ColumnIndexVector`.

How can I remove a number if it exists in the `vector`?

Comment: @Evg Oops! Just updated the code.

Comment: what is `mGrid` ? Please post a [mcve] and the complete error message

Comment: You cannot erase by index, it must be an iterator.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That was not relevant to the issue so I simplified the code to just a `bool` variable.

Comment: @Quimby it is not "index". The integer being passed is a item value in the vector.

Comment: if it is not relevant then you can create a [mcve] without `mGrid`

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Okay, then follow what Evg said.

Comment: @Evg - I am trying that code in the other answer. *But* how do we determine the number of items erased?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I did do that!!!

Comment: From your code you don't need a number of items, only the fact that at least one item was erased. You can find that by checking an iterator value returned by `std::find()` or `std::remove()` against `m_vColumnIndexesToExclude.end()`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You didn't do a [mcve]. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/cn6Tf1aoj The example isn't complete nor verifiable.

Comment: Note that if you want to erase several elements, it is generally more efficient and less error-prone to create a new vector instead of trying to modify several times the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

This is the error that my compiler says (after adding definitions that you forgot):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::erase(int&)'
   22 |         if (m_vColumnIndexesToExclude.erase(iColumn) > 0)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/vector:67,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1430:7: note: candidate: 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::vector<int>::iterator; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::vector<int>::const_iterator]'
 1430 |       erase(const_iterator __position)
      |       ^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1430:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'std::vector<int>::const_iterator'
 1430 |       erase(const_iterator __position)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

As the compiler explains to you, there is no erase function that would accept an `int` as an argument. There is an erase function that accepts an iterator. The iterator is what you must pass to erase an element from a vector.

The typical way to erase all elements with particular value is the erase-remove idiom. With certain pre-conditions you have more efficient options available:

- If the container is sorted, then you can do binary search using `std::lower_bound` for single element or `std::equal_range` for multiple.
- If the container isn't sorted and you don't need to keep the order, then you can do a linear search, `swap` with last element, and `pop_back`.

---

However, considering the apparent use case, an unsorted vector would be an inefficient choice. `std::unordered_set` would likely be more efficient if there are many indices.